# convert input date codeigniter to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, date

iam student have homework codeigniter. i want to creat form input student, and i have input date in that form. i used this code for input date:

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="seminar_proposal"
  value="<?php echo $seminar_proposal; ?>" required>
```

that form have format date `dd-mm-yy` but mysql have format `yyyy-mm-dd` then data mysql doesn't change.
i used Controller, Model, and Views to call that form input can you help me what and where can i add function or code to convert them?.
i really hope the answer :)
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert when output date

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="seminar_proposal"
  value="<?php echo date('d-m-y', $seminar_proposal); ?>" required>
```

and convert string when process

```
$mysql_date = DateTime::createFromFormat(
  'd-my-y', $_GET['seminar_proposal'])->format('Y-m-d');
```